# How do I save an image from CapturePreviewAsync stream?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, async-await, webview2

I don't understand much about `Async`, but I get no errors when running this, and still I don't get an image in C:\temp\test.jpg - what am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub WebView22_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles WebView22.Click
    grabpic()
End Sub

Public Async Function grabpic() As Threading.Tasks.Task
    Dim ms As System.IO.Stream
    Await (WebView22.CoreWebView2.CapturePreviewAsync(CoreWebView2CapturePreviewImageFormat.Jpeg, ms))
    Dim file As New System.IO.FileStream("C:\temp\test.jpg", IO.FileMode.Create)
    ms.CopyTo(file)
    ms.Close()
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. You're not awaiting the `graphics()` function, and therefore exceptions are being silently swallowed. Also, I'm not exactly sure what triggers the `Click` event of a WebView2 control (assuming it can actually be triggered). So, instead, you probably should test using a button click, for example.
2. You're not initializing `ms` at all, which will cause a NullReferenceException. You probably wanted to create an instance of `MemoryStream`.
3. You're calling `ms.CopyTo` *after* writing to the stream. At that point, the current position will be at the end of the stream and nothing will be written to `file`. You either need to set the position at the beginning (i.e., `ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` or use `ms.WriteTo()` instead.

With that, the `graphics()` method would look something like this:

```
Public Async Function grabpic() As Task
    Using ms As New IO.MemoryStream()
        Await WebView22.CoreWebView2.CapturePreviewAsync(
            CoreWebView2CapturePreviewImageFormat.Jpeg, ms)
        Using file As New IO.FileStream("C:\temp\test.jpg", IO.FileMode.Create)
            ms.Seek(0, IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
            ms.CopyTo(file)
        End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

**However**, you don't really need a MemoryStream in this case. You could just write directly to the FileStream. Here's what the final code should look like:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await grabpic()
End Sub

Public Async Function grabpic() As Task
    Using file As New IO.FileStream("C:\temp\test.jpg", IO.FileMode.Create)
        Await WebView22.CoreWebView2.CapturePreviewAsync(
            CoreWebView2CapturePreviewImageFormat.Jpeg, file)
    End Using
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am trying what you suggest, but get this error: Error BC30002 Type 'Task' is not defined. related to Public Async Function grabpic() As Task

Comment: @Thomas What version of .NET are you using? Try `...As Threading.Tasks.Task` as it was in your original code or add `Imports System.Threading.Tasks` at the top of your file.

Comment: It just needed to be Threading.Tasks.Task - you are a life saver. Thank you so much for helping me out here.